# Uploading image from react native to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have been looking for reference but I really can't find the issue why I can't find the reason why I am not able to upload image to the firebase storage. I am pretty sure that it is working as I am able to work authentication.

I even follow tutorials but for them, it is working. There is no error appearing but it doesn't upload for some reason and I am really frustrated already. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

const Home = () => {
  const [img, setImg] = useState();

  function choosePic(){
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: false
    }).then(async (image) => {
      try {
        setImg(image);
        const imageName = image.path.substring(image.path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        const bucketFile = `image/${imageName}`;
        const pathToFile = image.path;
        await storage().ref(imageName).putFile(pathToFile);
        const url =  await storage().ref(bucketFile).getDownloadURL();
        console.log('image url', url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={{ uri: img?.path}} style={{ width: 100, height: 100}}/>
      <Button title='Add photo' onPress={choosePic} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

EDIT:

I wasted a lot of time looking for a relevant issue and found out that it is just taking too long to upload even the file size is below 1 MB (not even close).

Please help, even for authentication to login. It is also slow. My internet is fast and still don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Are you using the Firebase SDK or a react native wrapper?

Comment: Hello @RafaelZasas , I lost many time and confirmed that it is working BUT logging in and uploading an image (even it's only 1.5 kb) it takes a year to upload it. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would suggest using the official Firebase SDK to interact with Firebase services. If it still takes long to upload I would post a separate question with your code.